# Add highlighting and keyboard support to @ autocomplete suggestion

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies, autocomplete

I just noticed the new `@` autocomplete for comments.

When I hover over the suggestion, could it highlight the user's comments attached to the post?

Also, what about up/down arrow key support?

Comment: +1 for arrow key support. My mouse is too far away.

Comment: What's wrong with the tab key? I feel that's much more natural for this kind of thing than the arrow keys. /cc @Matt

Comment: @balpha: Ooo, that's fancy. I guess because the username is shown ***above*** the cursor, my first instinct was to press the up key to try get to it...

Comment: @balpha - with most autocompletes, up/down select something. with this it just moves the cursor in the textbox.

Comment: @balpha up/down was my first instinct too, as autocompletes from all other sites I've used function this way.  Thanks for the tip, though

Answer (score 1):

It could also highlight the Editing card/section if your `@`tting an editor, or the question OP card/section for the OP.

Comment: Could it also prepare me toasts? `;-)`

Comment: Only waffles...

Comment: @LanceRoberts leggo of my eggo.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow up/down would be a great next step - I personally have gotten use to such functionality from both Google and other sites with autocompletion.

The highlighting the @users comment, should elaborated more.
What if @user has added more comments? Should all the comments be highlighted? Or just the latest comment.

If the latter, what if the last comment isn't the one you're referring to?

I like the idea of highlighting and to me, the most beneficial way to do it, would be highlighting the latest comment. Even if I was referring to a earlier comment.